# Looking at x86 machine code, how do I determine the starting location of the next instruction?

Tags: assembly, x86, disassembly, machine-code

The instructions in x86 machine code are variable length. I've studied [the x86 instruction set](http://ee.usc.edu/%7Eredekopp/cs356/slides/CS356Unit4_x86_ISA.pdf) thoroughly. I've read about [how to convert assembly to machine code](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Machine_Language_Conversion). But I didn't see in any of my studying so far (maybe I missed something) how the processor knows where one instruction ends and the next begins.

Take the following:

```
XOR CL, [12H] = 00110010 00001110 00010010 00000000 = 32H 0EH 12H 00H
XOR CL, 12H = 10000000 11110001 00010010 = 80 F1 12
```

If I'm looking at:

```
00110010 00001110 00010010 00000000 10000000 11110001 00010010 ...
32H 0EH 12H 00H 80 F1 12 ...
                ^
How do I know the next instruction starts here?
```

When I was studying the OSI model in networking, packets would solve the variable layer size problem by including a value at the start of each component telling you how much content the layer would contain. But CPU instructions are much more compact than packets and don't seem to contain that.

Why? What am I trying to do, really?

My goal is to analyze the machine code of a program (**without a disassembler** - I need maximum processing speed to analyze large volumes of data, and a disassembler does more work than I need to do, like mapping the binary to string syntax) and record certain statistics about the opcodes used. But I obviously have to figure out where one instruction ends and the next begins to do that.

Looking at x86 machine code, how do I determine the starting location of the next instruction?

Comment: There's no simple way to do that, unfortunately. You don't need to write a full-fledged disassembler to do it, but you do need to have the instruction encoding tables in your program in order to write a length decoder for an arbitrary instruction, given its start address.

Comment: Note that obfuscated executables can make it hard for static disassembly: if you simply start from the top of the `.text` section like `objdump -d` does, you're assuming there are never any jumps back into the middle of what you thought was an instruction, or forward into something that decodes differently if you don't skip the jumped-over byte: [x86 Assembly two jump instructions with the same target](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45775933).  Linear disassembly is fine for x86 executables produced by normal compilers like GCC and clang, though; they don't mix data and code.

Comment: @PeterCordes my project actually revolves around the concept of defeating obfuscation, so this is already something I'm looking out for. There's no limit to how many times an attacker's obfuscation technique can redirect control flow, it could do so between every instruction if it chose, and even `jmp` to another `jmp`. I'll be establishing a baseline from a large control-set of innocent executable code and I believe any extreme levels of control flow redirection should stand out from the norm. Anything non-extreme won't inhibit analysis.

Comment: @J.Todd: Note that obfuscation can use `jcc` on a value that you can't easily statically compute; you'd have to actually run the program to know if it was always or never taken.  Also, it only takes one `jmp` to get decoding out of sync and give you the "wrong" decode for multiple instructions until decoding happens to get back in sync (this does tend to happen in practice within several instructions, although in general x86 machine code is *not* self-synchronizing and you could in theory construct a string of bytes that decode 2 different ways for a long time before a common insn end point)

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for the heads up, that's valid, however: They can only do that to a certain extent before the executable's ratio of control flow operations far exceeds even the upper average of what's normal in any executable and I can categorically flag the file as being worth having a look at (with some false positive analysis being acceptable). Beyond that I'm analyzing certain relationship patterns in the logic that I think the attacker won't be able to obfuscate away fully without triggering certain categorical "this looks fishy" thresholds.

Comment: @PeterCordes to counter myself, I'll add that the attacker can add in equivalent dead-code instructions to balance the ratio of jump ops to non jump ops ... but at that point you're looking at significant overhead file size as a consequence, making the payload's upload harder to hide. I guess that's not a good enough argument, since 95% of the payload can be encoded as image data, with the decoder being the only machine code you'd definitely have an opportunity to analyze, and decoders are small... It's a challenging task. Hoping machine learning can help.

Comment: @J.Todd: You're talking about obfuscating the entire code.  I don't generally look at obfuscated code, but I thought it was more common to just have one "critical" block of anti-debugger / license-key check code or something obfuscated.  Even one tricky jump over a `0f` byte or something could throw off decoding for enough of that block to stop some would-be attackers that don't know machine-code tricks.  Scattering read-only data between functions could also fool naive disassembly that doesn't trace jumps from a known starting point like IDA does.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223100/discussion-between-j-todd-and-peter-cordes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's just no explicit marker. You need to decode each instruction in turn. Each instruction has a certain length, the next instruction follows immediately afterwards.

If you look at more modern variable-length encodings such as UTF-8, you'll find that they are more logically defined than the x86 instruction set. That's just a consequence of lessons learned. ARM learned the lesson too, and made all instructions 32 bit.

Comment: ... and then invented Thumb2 to add back the mess.

Comment: @Ruslan: Thumb-2 is still sane enough that the first instruction word (16 bits) will tell you the length of the whole instruction (either 16 or 32 bits). With x86 you don't even know how many bytes of an instruction you need to parse before you know the length of the whole instruction. (Which can be anything between 1 and 15 bytes with prefixes)

Comment: Broad and off-topic note: With RISC instruction sets, I was particularly interested learning about them being the same length because it occurred to me that instruction sets of equal chunks can be accessed in parallel more easily, so I would actually be able to perform the analysis I'm doing with CUDA against RISC machine code. Which makes me wonder: Could a feature be added to RISC to say "when this instruction is triggered, the 3rd, 4th, 15th instruction forward, and 13th-67th instruction backward from here can be executed in parallel by multiple cores?

Comment: Basically, the compiler could notice that certain instructions at a certain point in the programs execution don't rely on each-other, and so include an instruction to execute them in parallel on multiple cores without the developer needing to go through the trouble of doing multi-threaded development. Only possible with RISC's equal length instructions though

Comment: @J.Todd: Won't fly, for practical reasons. Threads are far too expensive. And at a smaller scale, x86 already executes instructions in parallel. Each core has many Execution Units; each instruction is dynamically assigned to one EU based on its type and arguments.

Comment: @MSalters Ah thanks. Better to kill the idea while it's young before it grows and wastes resources :P

Comment: @J.Todd: Might want to ask Intel what happened to Itanium. The idea isn't entirely new, and the downsides are by now well-known.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223084/discussion-between-j-todd-and-msalters).

Comment: @J.Todd: Modern CPUs already find and exploit instruction-level parallelism by running independent instructions in parallel ([on multiple execution units within the *same* core](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/349972/how-does-a-single-thread-run-on-multiple-cores/350024#350024)).  This happens even on x86 where parallel decoding is hard and takes multiple pipeline stages.  (Modern x86 CPUs cache *decoded* instructions, to avoid decoding bottlenecks in high-throughput loops.)  Well-designed compact encodings like Thumb2 make length-decoding easy for HW to do in parallel.