# how to detect the instruction boundary while designing a disassembler?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, disassembly, machine-code, opcode

If I want to write a disassembler program, how can I determine the boundaries of instructions? By "boundaries," I mean the rule of separating a sequence of bytes into individual instructions.

For example, given the codes `FF 25 10 00 FF FF 38 11 FF 0A` (I made this up), how can we know whether it consists of two instructions `FF 25 10 00 FF` and `FF 38 11 FF 0A`, or only one `FF 25 10 00 FF FF`?

The most direct implementation method that comes to my mind is building an **opcode table**. When encountering a byte of data, we look it up in the opcode table to find all possible matching instructions (e.g., using a switch case statement). For example, `FF` can match *CALL* or *JMP* instructions. Then we further determine based on the next byte, just like the procedure I take when decoding machine codes myself.

Are there any other smarter ways to achieve this? If so, please let me know.

Comment: On x86, you won't get around decoding the instructions to find their lengths.

Comment: `FF 25` is the opcode+modrm for `jmp [rip+rel32]`, so it consumes another 4 bytes of machine code as the rest of the instruction.  There are some design features that make length decoding (given a starting point) cheaper, e.g. you don't need to account for all the REX bits to decode length from opcode+modrm, since R12 and R13 have some of the same restrictions as RSP and RBP.  ([rbp not allowed as SIB base?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52522544)).

Comment: But x86 machine code is a byte stream that's **not self-synchronizing**.  There's no way to look at a sequence of bytes and know which one starts a new instruction, other than decoding forwards from a known start point.  (And following relative branches, for disassemblers like IDA that attempt to be somewhat resistant to obfuscations, not just designed for simple compiler output like `objdump` is.)  [Is it possible to decode x86-64 instructions in reverse?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52415761)

Comment: [Looking at x86 machine code, how do I determine the starting location of the next instruction?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64370582) / [What happens if \`objdump -d --start-address\` starts printing from the middle of an x86 instruction?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75262864)

Comment: I've noticed the whole "not self-synchronizing" thing @PeterCordes mentioned when looking at a game boy debugger, and every time I scrolled up the disassembly, the top instruction would change because it was getting new data and the program refreshed the disassembly with a new starting point. That being said, I feel like there would be a way to figure out the odds of a given interpretation being correct based on context clues. Sometimes you can see something that just makes no sense within the context of the other instructions.

Comment: @puppydrum64: Yeah, you could probably train a model (perhaps using AI techniques) to predict whether an instruction sequence was nonsense or not.  In code that isn't intentionally obfuscated, it should work pretty well.